# startup and postCreate function in Dojo

Tags: javascript, dojo, dijit.form, dojox.charting

I am new to Dojo library, I come across `postCreate` and `Startup` functions in Dojo and I am getting difficulties to understand these two function in widget life cycle.

I did google and read in dojo documentation but no luck. Can someone explain it with lucid example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's simple , those method come with every widget that extend or inherit the [WidgetBase](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dijit/_WidgetBase.html) dojo class ,

Dojo widget passes thorough  different life cycle method , among those we find the last two method `postCreate`  and 'startup' ,

if you want `postCreate` comes just before startup in `lifecycle` , note that  `postCreate` just finished to create your widget but may not yet attached to dom , also its child widget not mounted ,

On the other hand the `startup` come after widget rendrer with it's child widgets and mounted to dom.

so if you have any layout calculation , or dom related function , you may not use postCreate for this , and should use staartup to ensure widget has finished mounting to DOM

Read more in [Doc](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dijit/_WidgetBase.html#id5)

Comment: thanks for your efforts to make it easy for me understand, now I got it when to use these lifecycle function for widget creation.

Comment: @TARUNPUNETHA you're welcome I'm glad that it helps you :)

Answer (score 0):

In general, you use postCreate for everything that you want to add to your widget (extra nodes, connect events) before the widget is shown.

startup is used after the widget is placed on the HTML dom and is mainly used when you have layout calculations or other layout widgets in your widget (Tabs, grid, containers, etc)
startup usually calls resize function that handles all layout calculations.

resize will be also called if your widget is inside a layout widget.